# How to filter data in an array that match a string?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have an array of data and I need to filter that data into a variable in react js.

**This is my array**

```
[{idappcontent: "Com_01", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Com_02", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Com_03", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_01", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Review1_Ques_02", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Sign_01", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Sign_02", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Thank_01", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"},
 {idappcontent: "Thank_02", idcontenttype: "0", idclient: "5"}
]
```

I need to get the data that contain "idappcontent == "Sign_" ". How to filter array data that match "Sign_" string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: `array.filter(o => o.idappcontent.startsWith("Sign_"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
const temp = YOURDATA.filter(item=> item.idappcontent.includes("Sign_"));
```

for more info:

1. The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
2. The includes() method performs a case-sensitive search to determine whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the javascript `filter` method with the `includes` method to filter the results.

Filter is a method that accepts a condition to filter the data;
Includes is a method that searches for the given value in an array (yes, string is an array-like type).

```
const signResults = array.filter(id => id.idappcontent.includes("Sign_"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following :

```
dataArray.filter(item => item.idappcontent.includes("Sign_"));
```